# Dropdown menu showing right (I'm doing it wrong)

Tags: html, css

EDIT: This was actually for my job but now I'll revert the changes and I just want this to be educational and learn what was the right way to do this... I hope I find the way :P

I'm working on a pre-existing site and I'm still learning a few things not that I'm stupid just amateur...

I know I'm missing something crucial but whatever example I see I still don't understand what I'm missing ... Sorry if this hurts your eyes... I really wanna know how to work around this efficiently :D

Site is http://alpha-ed.gr/

Trying to work my way on adding dropdown menu (it has none) that shows to the right.

I know I have to use

```
display:inline-block;
```

in this part, but also I know I'm doing it wrong :(

<s>If you go and see, I've left it the way I have it done (terrible),</s> what's supposed to be shown when I hover over the text is

"
Σειρά (centered and underlined)

(underneath)
Βιολογική καλλιέργεια και αγροτουρισμός
"

kind of like this http://jsfiddle.net/DL2af/

where "A" (trying to insert "Σειρά")  is on top and

"boystudent" (trying to insert Βιολογική καλλιέργεια και αγροτουρισμός)

is underneath it and do a second row "Σειρά" like that with a different section, but for now I want the 1st section.

This is what I came up with

```
<a class="nav show" href="?view=bc&id=9">Βιολογική Γεωργία και Διατροφή</a>
<span class="right-caret right">
<ul class="rightMenu">
<li>
  <a class="nav" href="?view=bc&id=9"><u>Σειρά</u><br>
  Βιολογική καλλιέργεια και αγροτουρισμός</a>
</li>
</span>
```

And CSS is

```
.show {display:inline-block;}

.rightMenu {
position:relative;
float:right;
}
.right-caret {

border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
border-top: 4px solid transparent;
border-left: 4px solid #000000;
display: inline-block;
height: 0;
opacity: 1;
vertical-align: top;
width: 0;

}
.right
{
float:right;
}
```

The normal way for the other ones is

```
<a class="nav" href="?view=bc&id=4">Μεσολόγγι</a><span class="hide"> | </span>
```

with it's CSS

```
.nav {
background:#FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
color:#000000;
display:block;
margin-top:8px;
padding:5px 4px 4px 10px;
position:relative;
/*text-transform:uppercase;*/
width:140px;
}

.nav:hover,.active {
background:#FFFFFF url(../images/menuhover.jpg) top left repeat-x;
border:1px solid #909090;
color:#303030;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: so it is working in fiddle but not on your site

Comment: yeah exactly :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In your HTML add this to get the dropdown list:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Σειρά </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#"> Βιολογική καλλιέργεια και αγροτουρισμός </a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add this to your CSS script to make it drops when you hover:

```
    /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: You can again check it out done it as you said and need this one thing before I make it as I like :P ... I'm using the inline-block; on .dropbtn and .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content, but it still shows it down not on the right

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input but I still have problems making the dropdown content shown on the right... even though it says in the right places inline-block; I tried putting it everywhere and everytime it just does nothing or breaks the code ... I edited my post... So I reverted all the changes... I'm doing this now for educational purpose... Hope I find the answer later

Comment: @ToomanyQuestiondude I didn't forget you, I'm trying to find a better solution for you :)

Comment: Okay :D ... Didn't ask you to keep trying but thanks :D